# How to get timestamp of an event log in emitted event from smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-design, events

I want to get the timestamp of an event.

How can I get time of event fired, if the event data does not contain any time value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by checking the timestamp of the block that the event was included in. For something like web3.js, you can use [`getBlock`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html?highlight=getBlock#getblock):

`web3.eth.getBlock(blockHashOrBlockNumber [, returnTransactionObjects] [, callback])`

Additionally, you can include the timestamp in the event itself. It would look like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.5;

contract MyEvetTest {

   event MyEvent(uint256 timestamp);

   function myFunction() public {
       emit MyEvent(block.timestamp);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, perfect answer, exactly to the point .

Comment: Great. Feel free to "accept" the answer, so that future viewers will know that this answer solved your issue.

Comment: I checked entire page, and didn't found any button like "accept", don't know where that gone, here is only two options "share" and "edit" , otherwise I would not have replied thanks in comment because accept=thanks

Comment: There is a check mark under the up and down vote arrows. Try clicking on that to accept.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't store timestamp in event, you can parse like this

```
const getTimeByBlock = async(txHash) => {
  const blockN = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)
  const blockData = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockN.blockNumber)

  return blockData.timestamp
}
```